# Excel VBA to Copy Column from one sheet to another based on a second columns cell value

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I tried this, which returned the rows I want, so a good start.  But I really just need the value in Column B, not the entire row.  What I really want is to list the value in column B if the value in column C is <>"" and column D <>"". Results in Quote sheet starting in cell C4.

```
Sub CopyQuoteValues()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    A = Worksheets("Software Options").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Quote").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If B = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Quote").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Software Options").Range("C17:C" & A)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) <> "" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Quote").Range("A" & B + 1)
            B = B + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you need:

```vb
Sub CopyQuoteValues()

    Dim wsOpt As Worksheet, wsQuote As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rngDest As Range
    
    Set wsOpt = Worksheets("Software Options")
    Set wsQuote = Worksheets("Quote")
    
    Set rngDest = wsQuote.Range("C4")
    
    For Each c In wsOpt.Range("C17", wsOpt.Cells(wsOpt.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Len(c.Offset(0, 1)) > 0 Then 'value in C and D ?
            c.Offset(0, -1).Copy rngDest       'copy ColB
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next paste location
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Now I need to bring over just the value, not the formatting.

Comment: `rngDest.Value = c.offset(0, -1).value`

Comment: Runtime Error 424  Object required